# Eval a string like a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have these two arrays

```
strings1 = ['text1a','text1b']
strings1 = ['text2a','text2b']
```

I want to use string.join with a dash dynamically to get this.

```
text1a - text1b # "-".join(strings1)
text2a - text2b # "-".join(strings2)
```

However, I don't make that with these two lines above commented. I'd like to make this dynamically so:

```
array_vars = [
    'strings1','strings2' # referencing every array
]

# and make a loop
for x in array_vars:
    print("-".join(x))  # in this line I hope evaluate x like a var (strings1 or string2, or stringsN.
```

And, is it possible to get name of every item from list?

```
strings1 = ['football','tennis']
strings2 = ['cards','dominoe']

texto ='I am playing dominoe'

array_vars = [
    strings1,
    strings2
]

# and make a loop
for x in array_vars:
    print(f'{x}', re.search('|'.join(x), texto, re.I))  #
```

And get item's name instead its values.

**strings2**  instead  **['cards', 'dominoe']**

```
for x in array_vars:
    print(f'{x}', re.search('|'.join(x), texto, re.I))  # 

# I got  this...
# ['football', 'tennis'] None
# ['cards', 'dominoe'] <re.Match object; span=(13, 20), match='dominoe'>
```

Any idea or suggestion?  Yes... this.

I just changed the array to a dict

```
array_vars = {
    "strings1":strings1,
    "strings2":strings2
}

# and make a loop
for x in array_vars:
    print(x, re.search('|'.join(array_vars[x]), texto, re.I))  #
```

I got

```
strings1 None
strings2 <re.Match object; span=(13, 20), match='dominoe'>
```

Comment: `# referencing every array` Why do you have a list of variable names as strings? Don't do that. Just use a data structure that associates the names to those objects *directly*.

Comment: Or in this case, just a `list` with all those other lists.

Comment: i.e. `data = [strings1, strings2]` then `for x in data: print("-".join(x))`

Comment: So, I got useful you said